# Unity flashback: how to stop downloads clearing the Nautilus 'recent files' 'place'

Tags: unity, nautilus

Each time I download a file nautilus clears the 'recent files' list.
How do I set Nautilus to retain the recent files list?

I go on the net: I do research: I select a file [pdf, xls, odt etc etc]: I select 'download'. 
The selected file downloads fine but The Nautilus 'Recent Files' list is wiped and all that shows is the file just downloaded.

UPDATE
Synaptic now says the following are installed: 
ubuntu 14.04, 
nautilus1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11, 
gnome-shell3.10.4-0ubuntu5.2,
gnome-session-flashback 1:3.8.0-1ubuntu12.2, 
Unity 7.2.6+14.04.2016.04.08-0ubuntu1

As no one seems to have an answer should I log this as a bug?

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "download a file"  ? Describe exactly what you are doing and what software you're using.

Comment: I go on the net: I do research:

Comment: Sorry if this post is a mess: I hit return for a new line -- the comment to that point is sent! - - I try to amend the erroneously sent mms -- a dilague says amendments can only be made within 5 minutes - - I have no idea where I am with this.     thanks @RoVo. I go on the net: I do research: I select a file [pdf, xls, odt etc etc]: I select 'download'.               Synaptic says the following are installed: ubuntu 10.04, nautilus1.13.10.1-0ubuntu9.11,    gnome3.2.8-1

Comment: thanks @RoVo. I go on the net: I do research: I select a file [pdf, xls, odt etc etc]: I select 'download'. Synaptic says the following are installed: ubuntu 10.04, nautilus1.13.10.1-0ubuntu9.11, gnome3.2.8-1